# Java Web Application Security Idea

Tags: java, security, jsp, servlets, web

I search a lot in Google and Stackoverflow about web application security in Java but I can not understand which one is best pattern for my web application.

I want to use JSP/Servlet and my web server is Tomcat .

Web application security is very important for us but I really did not know what I have to ? or What is the Best way ?!

I studied about Tomcat Realm , Acegi , Spring Security .....

Thank you.

Comment: If security is important, then it is very important that you understand the security mechanisms in you application. The frameworks in Tomcat and Spring may be quite flexible and powerful, but they are also quite complex. If you go for one of them, be sure that you understand them well so that you don't introduce a security hole by making a faulty configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Spring go with Spring Security(Acegi is old version of Spring security). If not use [Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/).I am not in favor of tomcat realm because of server dependency and unit testing.

Answer (score 2):

Take a good look at Container Managed Authentication. It's part of the Servlet Specification, so not server-dependent. Most of the hard work is done by the container. You just have provide a JAAS LoginModule that interfaces to your user database, authenticates him, and sets up his roles. The rest of it is just web.xml configuration of what URLs require what roles to access them.

Comment: I think this method is very static because every time I changed the role or add new one I have to restart tomcat. I need something more flexible...

Answer (score 0):

I would also vote for Spring security. There is a latest Spring 3.0 version not the ACEGI security
and its quiet flexible. Make sure you understand the semantics. Please have a look at

[Spring Security Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity.html)

There are some sample applications which come bundled. You can download either of them, deploy the war inside tomcat, and have a look at the example code in order to get the better understanding. 
Hope this helps,
Ben